# Use inclusion-exclusion principle to count permutations where no number $i$ is followed by $i+1$

Tags: combinatorics

$a_n$ is the number of permutations of $[n]$ in which no number $i$ is immediately followed by $i+1$. I need to use the Inclusion-Exclusion principle to get a formula for $a_n$.

In this case I know the universe is all permutations of $[n]$ and the "bad" elements are permutations where some $i$ is followed by $i+1$.  I think I want something of the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{S \subseteq [n]} (-1)^{|S|}|\cap_{i \in S}A_i|
\end{align*}
Where bad permutations are represented by $A_i$ but this is where i get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For $k\in[n-1]$ let $A_k$ be the set of permutations of $[n]$ in which $k$ is immediately followed by $k+1$.

- Show that $|A_k|=(n-1)!$.
- More generally, show that if $S\subseteq[n-1]$, $\left|\bigcap_{k\in S}A_k\right|=(n-|S|)!$; it doesn’t matter whether $S$ contain adjacent integers.

Then substitute into the [inclusion-exclusion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement)

$$\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne S\subseteq[n-1]}(-1)^{|S|-1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in S}A_k\right|$$

and subtract from $n!$.

Comment: I am not great with using the inclusion exclusion principle, I am not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: @Mroog: I added a little more detail to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok i think I see where to go, would you end up with something like $n! - \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k(n-k)!$ ?

Comment: @Mroog: Almost: it’s $$n!-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}(n-k)!=n!+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k(n-k)! =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(n-k)!\;.$$ Subsets of $[n-1]$ have a maximum size of $n-1$.